# How to configure SMTP in Bugzilla?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, bugzilla

I installed bugzilla in my AWS(Ubuntu 14.04) instance. Now it is running fine when i do like...

```
http://*.*.*.*/bugzilla
```

Now i'm going to configure SMTP here is my config

```
mail_delivery_method :: SMTP
mailfrom :: abc@gmail.com
smtpserver :: smtp.gmail.com:465
smtp_username :: abc@gmail.com
smtp_password :: ********
```

when i try to create a new account it gives me an error like below...

[image: Bugzilla error]

is there anything i have to do at AWS for using SMTP?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Is there a setting to turn on SSL or TLS? That is required to use gmail as an SMTP sender.

Comment: There was an error sending mail from 'mailid1' to 'mailid2': failed AUTH: 5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsO 5.7.14 ZN7PLeug63BfiJmBWwnNKALcmyomVzcre-MiL_PkApXgHm40qb60Lanv6tXYhobK4fAOtg 5.7.14 egvQAr4eKB13OeYuqissFYG8cBPXogBFEIz2MMz58p7cc-t2P5QHeRPTsTlN7mWByqIaSa 5.7.14 oeZIugkTP7ttB7asw7QqDemnwpfXDkRGRWNK1yoKGBd3ZN_zuFYtVfh13jiz7jJLHqi5PQ 5.7.14 hi248vW3rwLAODc1uO1_4VkWvGsio> Please log in via your web browser and 5.7.14 then try again. 5.7.14 Learn more at 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 o31sm31475808qtf.20 - gsmtp Now this eror

Comment: Thanks.. I solved the issue by enabling less secure apps to ON.